# How to handle javascript action and submit form action on a same button

Tags: javascript

In my form, I am trying to run one javascript function to compare 2 textbox values. also, In that same button, i am trying to perform submit action to save the form data to DB and redirect to next page. JS function works fine, it generates alert for wrong input, but as soon as I click on alert. It is redirecting to next page without saving form data to DB. Can anyone tell me how to stop this?

I want to do:

1. Compare 2 textbox values; if they are the same form should submit and save to DB(working)
2. If values are not matching then show alert(working), but it on clicking "ok" it should not redirect until the values are right for both textboxes.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j072o54d/20/)

```js
function check(){

  var fistInput = document.getElementById("total").value;
  alert(fistInput);
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  if(fistInput === secondInput)
  {
    alert("Good");
  }
  else if(fistInput > secondInput)
  {
    alert("Please input correct value");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Please input correct value");
  }
  
}
```

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="print-receipt.php" method="post" name="myform" autocomplete="off" >
  <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="Total Amount"  name="total" required>
  <input type="text"  id="amount"  placeholder="Total"   name="amount">
  <button  type="submit" name="submit" onclick="check()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) when form data is invalid, to prevent the form from being submitted.

Instead of `onclick` on your `type='submit'` button, use `onsubmit` handler on your `<from>` element. You can pass an `event` to your function like this:

```
<form onsubmit='check(this)'></form>
```

```js
function check(event){

  var fistInput = document.getElementById("total").value;
  alert(fistInput);
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  if(fistInput === secondInput)
  {
    alert("Good");
  }
  else if(fistInput > secondInput)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please input correct value");
  }
  else
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please input correct value");
  }
  
}
```

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="print-receipt.php" method="post" name="myform" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="check(this)">
  <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="Total Amount"  name="total" required>
  <input type="text"  id="amount"  placeholder="Total"   name="amount">
  <button  type="submit" name="submit"  >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @wscourage, Hey it helped but still the form data is not storing in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("f");
function check(){
  var fistInput = document.getElementById("total").value;
  alert(fistInput);
  var secondInput = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  if(fistInput === secondInput) {
    alert("Good");
    form.action = "print-receipt.php";
  }
  else if(fistInput > secondInput) {
    alert("Please input correct value");
    form.action = "";
  }
  else {
    alert("Please input correct value");
    form.action = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="f" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="myform" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="Total Amount"  name="total" required>
  <input type="text"  id="amount"  placeholder="Total"   name="amount">
  <button  type="submit" name="submit" onclick="check()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```